# Manipulate Range.Adress value with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario:** I am working with a code that (alongside other things) gets me the location of the checkboxes in a worksheet in a xlR1C1 format.

**Objective:** Since I have to manipulate this value to perform other operations, I am trying to get that address into a usable pair of values (row and column) that I can use.

**What I already tried:** Somewhat in a convoluted way, I was able to read the addresses as string and do multiple operations to extract both numbers (with split, left and so on).

**Question:** Is there a better / more efficient way to perform this operation?

**Code:** Gets the checkbox location, and gets the first value (row number) from the address:

```
Sub getControlValues() 

    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    'Loop through Form Checkboxes
    For Each cb In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
        If cb.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                If cb.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = "X"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address(, , xlR1C1)
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3), "C")
                    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.Type
                ElseIf cb.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address(, , xlR1C1)
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3), "C")
                End If
            i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cb

End Sub
```

**Obs:** I know how to do this procedure easily within the sheet and can also use the macro recorder to do that, but my objective is to find a better solution for this.

Comment: Just use `Range.Row` and `Range.Column`?  (e.g. `cb.BottomRightCell.Row`)

Comment: @Chronocidal IDK how did I miss that. Many thanks friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Range.Row` and `Range.Column`? (e.g. `cb.BottomRightCell.Row`)

```
If cb.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = "X"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address(, , xlR1C1)
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3), "C") 'Nope!
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Row ' Tada!
```

*(Promoted from an "is there a reason you're not using this?" Comment to a full answer, so that the question can be flagged as answered - apparently the reason was "Oops")*